# libgdx input handling not working after backing from web page opened by clicking adView

Tags: android, libgdx, adview

I am creating an android game with libGDX framework.
My setting screen is implemented with scene2d.
I handled back button click event by implementing a inputProcessorAdapter class. Add that and  Stage to InputMultiplexer for input handling.

Everything works well **excepting after clicking adView on bottom of screen and then going back to the screen from google advertise web page.** Back key no longer can be captured by inputProcessorAdapter. And keyboard is also no longer shown when Textfield of Stage is focused.
Below is my input handling code.

```
inputProcessor = new InputProcessorAdapter() {
    @Override
    public boolean keyDown(int keycode) {
        if (keycode == Input.Keys.BACK) {
            // Go back to main menu
            stage.unfocusAll();
            Gdx.input.setOnscreenKeyboardVisible(false);
            SettingScreen.this.game.setScreen(new MainMenuScreen(SettingScreen.this.game));
        }
        return false;
    }
};

InputMultiplexer multiplexer = new InputMultiplexer();
multiplexer.addProcessor(inputProcessor);
multiplexer.addProcessor(stage);
Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(multiplexer);
```

Waiting for your answer or advice.

Answer (score 1):

Finally, I found solution inspired by a topic in official forum site.
[Lifecicle messed up by Admob](http://badlogicgames.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=11&t=6511)

Below is my solution code.

```
    adView.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAdClosed() {
            super.onAdClosed();
            gameView.requestFocus();
        }
    });
```

Comment: On Android 10 it doesn't work, did you know how to do that? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should add

```
Gdx.input.setCatchBackKey(true);
```

after your `setInputProcessor` call so the whole code should look like

```
...
Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(multiplexer);
Gdx.input.setCatchBackKey(true);
...
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your early answer. I have tried your solution but it still doesn't work. Actually I have added  `Gdx.input.setCatchBackKey(true);` in the `create()` method of libgdx game class from beginning.